# Can Tzitzit be thrown in the trash

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, kavod, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, is there any issue with throwing a garment/tallit with Tzitzit out in the trash? Do any  laws of Kavod apply to them, or no?